# How to remove query string while redirecting on a LiteSpeed server?

Tags: .htaccess, litespeed

Trying to remove the query string of some URLs while redirecting them. The site is running on a LiteSpeed server. All .htaccess files and rules should work regularly on it.

Server: LiteSpeed, php7.2 lsphp, other htaccess rules do work.

QSD (query string delete) parameter should remove the QS, but doesn't.

? at end of destination should remove the QS, but doesn't.

Maybe a bug in LiteSpeed htaccess handling?

Rules i've tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/de/abc(.*)$" "https://xx.nl/de/xyz/?"
RewriteRule ^/de/abc/ /de/xyz/? [NC,R=301,QSD]
RewriteRule ^/de/abc/ /de/xyz/ [NC,R=301,QSD]
RewriteRule ^/de/abc/ /de/xyz/? [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/de/abc(.*) /de/xyz/? [R=301,QSD]
```

Whatever I try, the query string remains.

Comment: Do you have LSCache installed?

Comment: Yes, LSCache is installed.